# Angular 8 [class] binding with if, else if, else

Tags: css, angular

so I have a pretty large component, that I am trying to make it as DRY as possible. However, I haven't found an easier way to do this: The parent is showing a list of child components, chat messages that I have active, and they can have three states:

1. unread and urgent unread and normal
2. read(no new messages)
3. no new messages

```html
<ion-grid>
  <ng-container *ngIf="unreadAndUrgent; else normal">
    <ion-row class="urgent">
      <!-- about 30-40 lines of further structuring -->
    </ion-row>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #normal>
    <ion-row [class]="unreadNormalMessages ? 'normal-css' : '' ">
      <!-- same 30-40 lines of further structuring as above -->
    </ion-row>
  </ng-template>
</ion-grid>
```

as you can see I am essentially repeating the same code as above which just makes it very bloated in the end and I am trying to cut it down so that it can be more DRY. Any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `[ngClass]="{'class-name':condition,'class2-name':condition}"`